# How to map i to enter insert mode when in visual mode?

Tags: vim, neovim

Tried adding this into my init.vim but isn't working.

```
xnoremap i <Esc>i
```

Comment: What is the use case for switching to insert mode from visual mode?

Comment: The mapping works for me when entered in the command line.

Comment: @phd huh... just tried it again and it worked. No idea what happened

Answer (score 0):

I must be tripping

```
xnoremap i <Esc>i
```